# Too much water in box cake mix batter. Can it be fixed?

Tags: cake

I added too much water in my box cake mix and I already mixed the 2 together. What can I do to save the cake? Could I add another box of cake mix to the batter?

Comment: Wait, if you have an extra box of cake mix, just discard the first one and start over. Its not like we're talking expensive ingredients here!

Comment: If (s)he added twice the amount of water, (s)he can just make two cakes, without adding water for the second one.

Comment: Step 1: Add second box box. Step 2: Adjust for water for two cakes. Step 3: Make two cakes. Step 4: Send me spare cake. :-)

Comment: I think what we need to establish first is whether the OP knows exactly how much extra water was added. If it was an accident and the OP has no idea how much extra then starting from scratch is prudent. If the OP knows exactly how much water added, then make a double batch by adding more water to double the batch.

Comment: If you *don't* know how much extra water you've added, but do have an extra box of cake mix, you could probably do pretty well by mixing up a fraction of the second box separately, then dumping the rest in the original batch and adding the remaining water until it's the same consistency as the small test batch.

Comment: And any water is too much water, IMHO.  Use milk or, my favorite, melted ice cream

Answer (score 7):

If you are only over by a small amount (¼ cup or less) just add half the volume of flour(±).  If you added a moderate amount of extra water(½ to 1 cup) add half the volume of flour and ½ tsp baking powder and sugar equal to ⅓ the flour. Cakes fixed this way will be slightly dry but serviceable, particularly given that you started with a boxed cake anyway.

Beyond that point just make a double recipe.

Answer (score 4):

If batter just looks a bit too loose then switching to a sheet pan should take care of it.

Sprinkling something absorbent onto the base of pan before pouring batter also helps: raisins currents even cookie crumbs (I save gingersnaps for baking) or fistful of fine semolina

Answer (score 3):

I just did this this morning when making cinnamon chocolate  swirl cake added 1 3/4 cups of water instead of 3/4  cups of water worried and not sure what to do  I just added 1 cup of pancake mix the complete kind and hoped for the best.  It took a little longer to cook but no one was the wiser and it was really good not too dry.  I guess I lucked out on this one.  Next time I will put my glasses on before mixing.  Hope this works for you also.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Complete pancake mix is a good idea if you have it; it will probably have leavening similar to the cake mix, along with some dry milk and maybe other things to make it less plain, so it'll be a little closer to the cake mix than just flour and baking powder. It won't be sweet, though; you might still find you want to add sugar.

Answer (score 3):

1 1/2 cups all purpose flour,
1 cup sugar,
2 teaspoon baking powder,
1/4 teaspoon baking soda,
Whisk together.  Add to cake mix until you get the right consistency.  I use this recipe to actually get a bigger yield out of a mix and then add a bit more liquid.  I keep the mixture in a mason jar.  Cake mixes are less ounces today and really helps getting 2 dozen versus 18 cupcakes without having to get another mix.

Answer (score 2):

I accidentally doubled the water to 1/2 cup but went ahead and baked it anyway. It turned out fine, more cake than brownie. My teen boys couldn’t care less. Picture shows what was left an hour after it came out of the oven.[image]

Answer (score 1):

I just did this on accident. I added 2 cups when i was supposeda add only 1. What i did bc i was lucky enuff to have a spare box, was added a little bit of cake mix to my mixture and mixed until it got to the correct consistancy. All worked out thankfully.

Answer (score 1):

Oh I can tell you what happens when you are old enough, distracted enough, not paying that much attention to what you are doing and dingy enough to not be able to remember if you added the water yet or not. I just did that and am the one who is guilty of all the above. I added the water called for ( 1 cup) as per the instructions on my French Vanilla Cake Mix and immediately knew the batter was too thin. I went ahead & poured it into my cupcake pan and baked it until the toothpick came out clean which was several more minutes than the box mix stated it should take. The cupcakes looked “off” but kind of ok. When they came out of the oven they were nice and puffy but as they cooled they deflated and shriveled up quite a bit. They look and taste spongy and kind of eggy too. But I like the taste, kind of soufflé-like. I had to make an entire new batch as they were supposed to be for a bake sale and they were far from picture perfect. But I have no problem polishing these little ditties off as a chef’s treat that is unique ugly but edible tasty blunder.

Answer (score 0):

I just used 1/2 box of a new cake mix box to save mine. I accidentally added an extra cup of water when it should have been only 1 1/4 cup. Came out good. Will try the pancake mix next time I make a mistake

Answer (score -1):

Yes, adding too much water into a cake batter can be fixed. What you have to do is

ADD: **"Cake Flour"** (*not regular flour*) so that it can have a thicker, fluffy and floppy texture. Test your texture by stirring it with a fork (in a vertical, circular motion).

Also, because Cake Flour does not have a flavor nor taste, you'd want to either add some POWDERED SUGAR for more taste or some WHITE SUGAR (not too much of either) because the it'll make your cake hard and crispy and it'll stop from properly rising as it should. It'll come out flat and firmer, especially around the edges if too much sugar is added. As for flavor, depending on the overall flavor of your cake, you can use ingredients like Vanilla Extract, Almond Extract, Lemon Extract, Cocoa Powder, etc. To make your cake come together and add fluffiness to it, add some baking soda to it and let it sit for about 5-10 minutes. Allow the Baking Soda to work it's magic. Baking Soda, after left sitting a while in the batter, makes your batter puffy and moussey. When it gets like that, your cake will have a wonderful texture. Then that's when you begin pouring your batter into your pan or pans. Sometimes you may not want to wait but you must wait for the baking soda it do what it needs to do in order to get the results your looking for. In reiteration, Yes, too much water in a box cake mix batter can be fixed.