# I put too much water in my cake mix!

Tags: substitutions, cake

I accidentally put 2 cups of water in one box of strawberry cake mix, and i was only supposed to put 1 cup. I dont have any extra boxes to start over with, and the consistency of it is too thin! How can i fix it?

Comment: you might find the answers here helpful: http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24256/too-much-water-in-box-cake-mix-batter-can-it-be-fixed?rq=1

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is no. There really is no good solution short of making a double batch. I'd recommend looking for cake recipes from scratch as you might have the ingredients on hand, or go to the store and buy a second cake box.