# Over watered single layer

Tags: cake

I put 1 cup of water in a single layer box recipe that only called for 1/2 cup. How much cake flour do I need to balance out the water?

Comment: I think if you want to balance your cake back out, you need to double all ingredients, not just the flour to compensate for doubling the water.

Comment: @dlb Sounds like an answer... :)

Comment: To expand on what dlb said -- you'd need to double the eggs, oil, baking powder, sugar, salt, and whatever else might be in there, so you can't just add flour

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Too much water in box cake mix batter. Can it be fixed?](http://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24256/too-much-water-in-box-cake-mix-batter-can-it-be-fixed)

Comment: Listing the ingredients in the cake mix used might help!

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, the box of cake mix has much more than just flour in it (dried milk, sugar, leaveners, flavoring etc...)... and it may not even use cake flour.

Your best bet will be to buy a second box of the same exact cake mix and double the remaining ingredients as well, so if the came mix calls for 1/2 cup water and an egg, you'll need to add a second egg.

Now, it's *possible* to come up with a list of ingredients you will need to add to save yourself a trip to the store but we'd probably need to know which cake mix you used to start with.