# How to fix cake mix after adding too much water

Tags: cake

I added 1/2 cup too much water and was supposed to add 1/2 cup oil instead.  I added 1/4 cup oil and the mix is still too runny    Do I add a tablespoon baking soda or baking powder   I do not have cake flour or pancake mix    Help

Comment: Unless you have a second box of cake mix sitting around, I don’t know if you can easily save this.  It *might* bake up into something edible, but likely with a different texture than expected.  I don’t know if cupcakes would be better than a larger cake (as they have more surface area) in this case, as it might turn them into popovers.

Comment: You would need to add extra cake ingredients to fix this - how much would depend on what the original recipe was. Doesn't have to be cake flour, any wheat flour should work without too much difficulty +/- texture..

Comment: Check the answers in this question: https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/24256/too-much-water-in-box-cake-mix-batter-can-it-be-fixed?rq=1